# How to make a button inside a class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a chunk of code for a cookie clicker, but When i try to put it in a class it doesn't work, giving me this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Travi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: click() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work
my code is as follows

```
from tkinter import*
import os
root = Tk()
class Main():
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Travi\\Downloads')
    cookies = 0
    grandmas =0
    gmaprice = 10

    cookiesIcon = Label(root,text = "Cookies you have:"+str(cookies))
    cookiesIcon.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
    gma = Label(root,text = "Grandmas you have:"+str(grandmas))
    gma.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    def click(self):
        global cookies,cookiesIcon
        cookies+=1
        cookiesIcon.config(text = "Cookies you have:"+str(cookies))
    def grandma(self):
        global cookies,grandmas,cookiesIcon,gma,gmaprice
        if cookies>gmaprice:
            grandmas+=1
            cookies-=gmaprice
            gmaprice+=5
            cookies.config(text = "Cookies you have:"+str(cookies))
            gma.config(text = "Grandmas you have:"+str(grandmas))
    photo=PhotoImage(file = "Cookies.gif")
    b = Button(root,command =click)
    b.config(image=photo)
    b.grid()
    gmaupgrade=Button(root,command =grandma,text = "Grandmas for sale")
    gmaupgrade.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you should look more into how classes work (the use of an `__init__` method, referencing `self` for variable management instead of `global` etc.) before you try to implement a button inside a class.

Comment: `command=self.click`

Comment: Sneaky Turtle, I say to you that is what I am trying to do by creating this, and Bryan, I tried, but it gives me the error that self is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I failed to see the other very glaring error. You need to put this code inside an `__init__`.

Comment: Okay I tried putting it in two different places, but they did one of two things, didn't show any screen, or  it didn't show the buttons

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you must first get a better understanding of how classes in python (and in general) work.

I have corrected a series of mistakes in your code; that is:
- add an `` function to initialize the class attributes.
- removed the `global` statements that are not useful; all class attributes are accessible within the class.
- corrected some variables that were wrongly used (`cookies` i/o `cookiesIcon` and `grandma` i/o `gma`)

```
from tkinter import*
import os
root = Tk()

class Main():

    def __init__(self):
#         os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Travi\\Downloads')
        self.cookies = 0
        self.grandmas =0
        self.gmaprice = 10

        self.cookiesIcon = Label(root,text = "Cookies you have:"+str(self.cookies))
        self.cookiesIcon.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.gma = Label(root,text = "Grandmas you have:"+str(self.grandmas))
        self.gma.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#        photo=PhotoImage(file = "Cookies.gif")
        b = Button(root, command=self.click)
#        b.config(image=photo)
        b.grid()

        self.gmaupgrade=Button(root,command=self.grandma, text = "Grandmas for sale")
        self.gmaupgrade.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
        root.mainloop()

    def click(self):
        self.cookies += 1
        self.cookiesIcon.config(text = "Cookies you have:"+str(self.cookies))

    def grandma(self):
        if self.cookies > self.gmaprice:
            self.grandmas += 1
            self.cookies -= self.gmaprice
            self.gmaprice += 5
            self.cookiesIcon.config(text="Cookies you have:" + str(self.cookies))
            self.gma.config(text="Grandmas you have:" + str(self.grandmas))


Main()
```

I hope this gives you a sense of what you need to do, and the desire to learn more.